# Trying to add Image to GWT module

Tags: image, gwt

GWT Newie here.

I want to add an image to my UI when the module is loaded.
I have the following code

```
public void onModuleLoad()
{
    Image widget = new Image("images/AU-wp5.jpg");
    RootPanel.get("").add(widget);
}
```

but I get a null pointer when calling RootPanel.get("").add(widget); 
The image exists ok in my /images folder. 
Does the "" string in my get("") methof have to match something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You must to set parameter as id of your element in html.

```
get("divid").add(widget);
```

for more info read [javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RootPanel.html#get%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: See also `RootPanel.get().add(widget)`.

Comment: If you use `RootPanel.get("divid").add(widget);` as described above, the image will be inserted wherever `divid` is located in the page.  If you use `RootPanel.get().add(widget);` as described above, the image will be added to the base root panel.